# Existing implementations of Trees in Java?

Tags: java, tree

I'm looking for any implementation of a pure Tree data structure for Java (that aren't graphical ones in java.awt), preferably generic.

With a *generic tree* I'd like to add elements that are not supposed to be sorted and do something like this:

```
TreeNode anotherNode = new TreeNode();
node.add(anotherNode);
```

…and then I'd like to traverse the nodes (so that I can save and preserve the structure in a file when I load the tree from the same file again).

Anyone knows what implementations exist or have any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: What am I missing? Are you looking for `java.util.TreeSet` or `java.util.TreeMap`? Define *tree*, please.

Comment: About a year ago I needed a tree implementation but couldn't find a suitable one, so I had to roll my own :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) defined in the `javax.swing.tree` package.  It contains methods `getUserObject()` and `setUserObject(Object)` allowing you to attach data to each tree node.  It allows an arbitrary number of child nodes for each parent and provides methods for iterating over the tree in a breadth-first or depth-first fashion (`breadthFirstEnumeration()` / `depthFirstEnumeration()`).

Also note that despite being resident in the `javax.swing.tree` package this class does not contain any UI code; It is merely the underlying model of `JTree`.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has a nice `Tree` data structure. It's a "General Balanced Tree." It's not exactly Java, but it's close, and can serve as a good model.

It is hard to believe, given how much is in the base Java libraries, but there is no good generic `Tree` structure.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) in the runtime are red-black-tree implementations.

Comment: Yes, they use a tree internally, but they aren't tree themselves

Comment: Also, internally they use a binary tree implementation and so would not provide the "generic tree" functionality requested by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to store arbitrary Java objects on the nodes, you could use the [W3C DOM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). It even comes with its own serialization format (I forget what it's called :-).